# Why is my image darker than normal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I'm having trouble with my images in my header. They are darker than they should be. Look at the banner/header of my website where the Facebook, Twitter, etc links are. Move your mouse over the pictures, and they should change to their respective colors. For some reason, they are darker than they should be. I figured this had something to do with their opacity going lower, but I can't find in my .css where their opacity would change. Can someone help me out?

My site is http://www.startingtofeelit.com/

As you can see from the Twitter icon that it should be, the one on the site is way darker.

http://www.startingtofeelit.com/wp-content/themes/rockwell_v1.7.1/icons/twitter_hover.png

In the first split second, the correct color seems to display, but then directly goes darker. Can somebody point out where in my css this mistake is? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I totally sympathise with your situation, but your question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow in its current form. See [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Chrome dev tools, I can see that your icon's `opacity` is set with inline styling to be `.5`. I changed the 'unhovered' state to be `opacity:1;`, but it smoothly transitions back down to `.5` when you hover. The dynamic inline styling is leading me to believe that some `Javascript` somewhere is controlling this.

I took a look at your scripts, and the culprit may be your `main.js` file.

(as an aside: you should also take the advice in your question's first comment to turn this into a better StackOverflow question!)

Comment: You were absolutely right, jmeas. I wouldn't have even thought to look in there. Thanks!